# How can I call a function with an object and array and have it add properties to the object?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript testing application that uses Selenium Web Driver. When setting up the code ready to test I am always using code similar to the following that sets up properties before testing a page. In this case it is the topic page so I have this code to set up a topic object and then add properties to it:

```
var topic = this;

topic.topicName = element(by.id('topicName'));
topic.topicVersion = element(by.id('topicVersion'));
.....
.....
topic.description = element(by.id('description'));
topic.topicHeader = element(by.id('topicHeader'));
topic.topicFooter = element(by.id('topicFooter'));
```

Is there a way that I could simplify this set up so as to avoid my having to code many times the call to the `element(by.id())`. Ideally I would like to just pass in an object and an array of the different fields and have some code execute the `element(by.id(` and add the properties to the object? Note that the property names I would like to have are those that match the element Ids.

Some hints on how I could do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
['topicName', 'topicVersion', ...].forEach(function(k){
    topic[k] = element(by.id(k));
});
```